# Insert multiple rows into a table with only one value changing

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have a table with the following columns:

field 1 | field 2 | field3 | field4

I want to insert multiple rows in this table, but the values of field1, field2 and field3 are identical for each row. Only the value of field4 will change.

Obviously I could insert each row separately but the resulting query would be a bit ugly, and I'm wondering if there is a more efficient / elegant way to do it.

I thought of something like this for example:

```
insert into my_table (field1, field2, field3, field4) values (foo, bar, baz, ('value one','value two','value three','value four'))
```

And the result would be:

```
field1 | field2 | field3 | field4
foo    | bar    | baz    | value one
foo    | bar    | baz    | value two
foo    | bar    | baz    | value four
foo    | bar    | baz    | value five
```

In practice, the 'field4' column is a string type, and the different values are known when I write the query. There's no need to get them from a table or anything (although if it's possible, i'm interested in a solution that can do it)
Is this posible or will I have to write each insert separately ?

EDIT: I've changed the question to be more clear about the data type of the changing column (general textual data) and where does the data come from. Sorry for those who have already answered without these information.

Thanks.

Comment: "Is this posible or will I have to write each insert separately ?" > The latter :-)

Comment: Where does the value for field4 come from? is it sequential number or something else?

Comment: Adding to Ramblin' Man's question, if you know all the values for field4 you could provide them as a `table valued function`, alter your `insert` to use a `select` instead of `values`?  and join those values from the function...

Comment: @DrCopyPaste Your answer seems like a solution that could work, but i'm not familiar with table valued function. I'll look for information but could you elaborate? I do know all the values for field4, and I could use a selec tinstead of values yes.

Comment: @Kaidjin I wrote it up as an answer

Comment: sry, as discussion in a comment showed functions cannot be used that way in oracle it seems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a variation on Nicholas Krasnov's answer with a `case` statement to set the string values:

```
insert into my_table(field1, field2, field3, field4)
select 'foo', 'bar', 'baz',
  case level
    when 1 then 'value one'
    when 2 then 'value two'
    when 3 then 'value three'
    when 4 then 'value four'
  end
from dual
connect by level <= 4;

select * from my_table;

FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3 FIELD4             
------ ------ ------ --------------------
foo    bar    baz    value one            
foo    bar    baz    value two            
foo    bar    baz    value three          
foo    bar    baz    value four
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7309b/1).

Adding more rows/values would just require a change to the `level` limit and extra `when` clauses to match. ([like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e021d/1)). You could also have an `else` with a warning in case you get a mismatch in the numbers. There's no special significance to which string value goes with which `level` value, incidentally.

Comment: How can i achieve same thing, if I have to pick field4 values from another table. Thank you.

Comment: Select from your table instead of from dual. There may be complications from repeated data with connect-by though. Give it a try, look for related questions if you hit that problem, and ask a new question (with a [mre]) if you can’t make it work.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to accomplish this would be taking advantage of the `connect by` clause of `select` statement to generate as many synthetic rows as you need.

Suppose `field1` to `field3` are of `varchar2` data type and the `field4` is of number data type, as the sample of data and `insert` statement you have provided imply, then you could write the following `insert` statement

```
Insert into your_table_name(field1, field2, field3, field4)
   select 'foo'
        , 'bar'   /* static string literals */
        , 'baz'
        , level  /* starts at 1 and will be increased by 1 with each iteration */
    from dual
 connect by level <= 5  /* regulator of number of rows */
```

Result:

```
FIELD1      FIELD2      FIELD3      FIELD4
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------
foo         bar         baz                  1
foo         bar         baz                  2
foo         bar         baz                  3
foo         bar         baz                  4
foo         bar         baz                  5
```

**Edit**:

If you want to literally see `value one`, `value two` and so on as values of the `fiedl4` column, you could change the above `insert` statement as follows:

```
Insert into your_table_name(field1, field2, field3, field4)
   select 'foo'
        , 'bar'          
        , 'baz'
        , concat('value ', to_char(to_date(level, 'J'), 'jsp'))          
    from dual
 connect by level <= 5
```

Result:

```
 FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3 FIELD4
------ ------ ------ -------------
foo    bar    baz    value one
foo    bar    baz    value two
foo    bar    baz    value three
foo    bar    baz    value four
foo    bar    baz    value five
```

If you want to populate the `field4` with absolutely random generated string literal you can use `dbms_random` package and `string()` function specifically:

```
Insert into your_table_name(field1, field2, field3, field4)
  select 'foo'
       , 'bar'          
       , 'baz'
       , dbms_random.string('l', 7)       
   from dual
connect by level <= 5
```

Result:

```
FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3 FIELD4
------ ------ ------ --------
foo    bar    baz    dbtcenz
foo    bar    baz    njykkdy
foo    bar    baz    bcvgabo
foo    bar    baz    ghxcavn
foo    bar    baz    solhgmm
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the data is not numeric and there is no logical sequence for this data. I've updated my question to be more clear, but thanks a lot, I didn't know this clause and it will definitely be useful to me someday.

Comment: @Kaidjin What does `value one` and so on mean? Where those data come from? Do you want to populate the column with a random varchar2 value or you literally want to see `value one`, `value  two` and so on as the value of that column?

Comment: This data is known when I write the query. I just have to insert multiple lines that are very similar to each other. There is no need to get the values from another table or something like that. I just want to factor several insert statements into one, when only one column changes from one insert to another. So they are not random, I have a list in the specifications.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to do it -- but probably cleaner and easier to write multiple insert statements:

```
insert into my_table
select 1,1,1,field
from (select 1 field from dual 
      union select 2 from dual 
      union select 3 from dual);
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5a1d7/1)

Comment: Thanks. I'm not accepting the answer yet as there may be more answers, but yours is an interesting solution. In my example it is indeed cleaner to use multiple insert statements but my real query is longer and more complex, and this may be a good solution.