# SQL Insert many rows - one value changes - number of rows is dynamic

Tags: mysql

I need to do do an insert where 2 values will be constant and the third will change. So, something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO 
    `example_table`(column_a, column_b,column_c)
SELECT 1, [3,4], 409187710
from `example_table`
```

Desired Result:

| column_a | column_b | column_c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 409187710 |
| 1 | 4 | 409187710 |

Just to be clear the number of values I need to insert into `column_b` will vary - sometimes I will need to insert 2 values, sometimes I may need to insert 10 values, but columns `a` and `c` will always have the same values. How do I perform such an insert?

My question differs from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227699/insert-multiple-rows-into-a-table-with-only-one-value-changing) in that a sql `case` statement will not suffice. This is a different kind of problem.

Comment: *but needs to be unique - meaning the insert shouldn't perform if all 3 values already exist in the table.* If according unique constraint is present in a table then trivial INSERT IGNORE solves the problem.

Comment: @Akina How do I go about performing such an insert?

Comment: what determines how many values you have to insert? And how do you get what values the variable column would take?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5bc493637622ff9a3b610abb305fab3c

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 8.0 has a new kind of statement: [VALUES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html).

```
mysql> create table example_table (column_a int, column_b int, column_c int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into example_table
    -> select 1, column_0, 409187710 from (values row(3), row(4)) as t;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from example_table;
+----------+----------+-----------+
| column_a | column_b | column_c  |
+----------+----------+-----------+
|        1 |        3 | 409187710 |
|        1 |        4 | 409187710 |
+----------+----------+-----------+
```

If you use a version of MySQL that doesn't support the VALUES statement, you can use this syntax:

```
mysql> insert into example_table 
    -> select 1, b, 409187710 from (select 3 as b union select 4) as t;
```

Comment: I am not sure this can be made into a dynamic solution.

Comment: t to be clear the number of values I need to insert into column_b will vary...

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. You do have to write code to format the SQL query. If only you knew someone who could write code... :-)

Comment: That seems almost rude, but I get where you are going.

Comment: Apologies if it is rude. I mean it as friendly teasing. The truth is at some point you do have to specify the values you want to insert, and those have to get into your SQL query somehow. I showed a couple of syntax forms that allow you to do it, but they do require you to write some SQL syntax. It should be pretty simple to append a variable number of terms to the syntax in your application, then execute the resulting string as an SQL statement.

Comment: A simpler syntax form is `INSERT INTO example_table VALUES (...), (...), (...)` but that requires you to repeat the non-changing values in each row constructor, which I understood you did not want to do.

Comment: Sadly I am using version 5.6

Comment: I gave an example in my answer that works with MySQL 5.6.

Comment: But you should think about when you will upgrade to MySQL 8. MySQL 5.6 has been end-of-life since February 2021, and MySQL 5.7 reaches its end-of-life in October 2023.